# How to understand "That is more or less all there is to it"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> That is more or less all there is to it.

This is a sentence quoted from "Double Preposition"(https://www.ultius.com/glossary/grammar/prepositions/double-preposition.html)

I don't get it.

---

By the way, in the same article, there is another sentence:

> here are a could basic guidelines for you about the double preposition

I think "could" is the typo of "couple". Am I right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but "I don't get it" is not a question. All the words are used normally. You could punctuate with commas around "more or less" does that make it clearer.  The answer to the second question is "yes".

Comment: And where would you put the the commas? I think understanding would come first, then the commas :-)

Comment: **more or less** = roughly, approximately, imprecisely, but with only insignificant details excluded. P.S. You're correct about the typo.

Comment: BTW, this "double preposition" stuff is nonsense, more or less.

Comment: Please limit question to one concern at a time. If someone answers your second question correctly and your first question incorrectly, it would be hard for the community to know if they should up-vote or down-vote the answer. If you have a quick question like "is this a typo?" you might ask in [chat].

Comment: If you exclude the "more or less" bit, you can look up the rest, for example here: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=that%27s%20all%20there%20is%20to%20it. Note that, to correct the typo, you need to replace **could** with **couple of**.

Answer (score 1):

The basic sentence is

> That is all.

Meaning there is no more to be said.

We take that further by saying:

> That is all there is to it.

The **it** is something we are explaining. The **all** are the things we have said about the **it** and we are now saying that we have fully described the **it**, there is no more to be said.

I don't consider such a sentence to be particularly helpful in most cases. When speaking it's the kind of thing one uses as a pause to collect ones thoughts before going on to say something substantial. In technical or educational writing I don't think such a sentence adds value.

To make the sentence then less helpful there is the addition of **more or less**, implying that that there is some additional information we haven't given

> That is, more or less, all there is to it.

As you say, **could** should have been **couple of**.